# JS Call PHP Function

Tags: php, javascript

I PHP code function, now I want the function will appear with button click.

Here is my PHP code function :

```
function prints()
{
    header('Content-type: application/excel');
    $filename = 'LEGO_PRODUCTION_RESULT_NG.xls';
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    $data = "<html xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'>
    <head>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <xml>
            <x:ExcelWorkbook>
                <x:ExcelWorksheets>
                    <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                        <x:Name>Sheet 1</x:Name>
                        <x:WorksheetOptions>
                            <x:Print>
                                <x:ValidPrinterInfo/>
                            </x:Print>
                        </x:WorksheetOptions>
                    </x:ExcelWorksheet>
                </x:ExcelWorksheets>
            </x:ExcelWorkbook>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>";

    echo $data;
}
```

HTML button :

```
<input type="button" value="Export to Excel"/>
```

So how can I add JS function to call the PHP function on click button?

Comment: ajax (filler) (filler)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are outputting a file with the attachment disposition, you can simply link to the PHP script:

```
<input type="button" value="Export to Excel" onclick="window.location='print.php'" />
```

`print.php` must call the `prints()` function and nothing else.

When clicked, the browser will not redirect the page, it will leave the current page intact and simply show the download prompt for the file.

Comment: Best solution. Zero javascript. Works on all browsers (even ancient ones, even with javascript turned off).

Comment: Please explain the downvotes? This is the best way to do it...

Comment: What do you think `window.location` is? @slebetman Also using inline JS is never the best solution

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 not sure who your comment is to, neither OP or I ever said anything about not using Javascript - question is tagged Javascript. Inline JS is not really my point, my point is the redirect, you can assign the JS lots of different ways, I am just trying to show the solution without getting bogged down with unrelated stuff.

Comment: Whatever. I didn't think your solution is really the best solution as you say so I used the mechanism provided to me and encouraged by SO (I downvoted). And the use of javascript comment was directed at @slebetman

Comment: SO also encourage constructive criticism which "-1 not best solution" is not, unless there is some obvious error in the answer (which in this case there isn't).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I gave the reason why I don't think this is the best solution.